# Extracting unique values from multiple files in Perl

Tags: perl, parsing, file

I have several data files that are tab delimited. I need to extract all the unique values in a certain column of these data files (say column 25) and write these values into an output file for further processing. How might I do this in Perl? Remember I need to consider multiple files in the same folder.

edit: The code I've done thus far is like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                   

use warnings;
use strict;

my @hhfilelist  = glob "*.hh3";

for my $f (@hhfilelist) {
  open F, $f || die "Cannot open $f: $!";
  while (<F>) {
    chomp;
    my @line = split /\t/;   

    print "field is $line[24]\n";
  }
  close (F);
}
```

The question is how do I efficiently create the hash/array of unique values as I read each line of each file. Or is it faster if I populate the whole array and then remove duplicates?

Comment: @davorg well i'm stuck with the basic problems itself. first how do I read multiple files one at a time. The next one being only considering the unique values as I read each file. I guess the Find::File package can be used.

Comment: @DVK yes is part of a larger code that is already in Perl.

Comment: You should not usually use split to parse X-separated files. In all but the most trivial cases, that's not sufficient - e.g. doesn't handle X (separator) being inside the field, or the fields being quoted. In trivial cases it works, though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
perl -F/\\t/ -ane 'print"$F[24]\n" unless $seen{$F[24]}++' inputs > output

perl -F/\\t/ -ane 'print"$F[24]\n" unless $seen{$F[24]}++' *.hh3 > output
```

Command-line switches `-F/\\t/ -an` mean iterate through every line in every input file and split the line on the tab character into the array `@F`.

`$F[24]` refers to the value in the 25-th field of each line (between the 24-th and 25-th tab characters)

`$seen{...}` is a hashtable to keep track of which values have already been observed.
The first time a value is observed, `$seen{VALUE}` is 0 so Perl will execute the statement `print"$F[24]\n"`. Every other time the value is observed, `$seen{VALUE}` will be non-zero and the statement won't be executed. This way each unique value gets printed out exactly once.

---

In a similar context to your larger script:

```
my @hhfilelist  = glob "*.hh3";
my %values_in_field_25 = ();
for my $f (@hhfilelist) {
  open F, $f || die "Cannot open $f: $!";
  while (<F>) {
    my @F = split /\t/;
    $values_in_field_25{$F[24]} = 1;
  }
  close (F);
}

my @unique_values_in_field_25 = keys %values_in_field_25; # or sort keys ...
```

Answer (score 3):

For Perl solution, please use `Text::CSV` module to parse flat (X-separated) files - the constructor accepts a parameter specifying a separator character. Do this for every file in a loop, with file list generated by either `glob()` for files in a given directory or `File::Find` for subdirectories as well

Then, to get the unique values, for each row, store the column #25 in a hash.

E.g. after retrieving the values:

```
 $colref = $csv->getline($io);
 $unique_values_hash{ $colref->[24] } = 1;
```

Then, iterate over hash keys and print to a file.

---

For non-Perl shell solution, you can simply do:

```
cat MyFile_pattern | awk -F'\t' 'print $25' |sort -u > MyUniqueValuesFile
```

You can replace `awk` with `cut`

Please note that non-Perl solution only works if the files don't contain TABs in the fields themselves and the columns aren't quoted.

Comment: I've used the glob() function successfully. But I'm new to perl so am kinda confused abt the part you talk abt storing the values in a hash and iterating over it? can you tell me how?

Answer (score 3):

Some tips on how to handle the problem:

- Find files

  - For finding files within a directory, use [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html): `glob '.* *'`
  - For finding files within a directory tree, use [`File::Find`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html)'s `find` function
- Open each file, use [`Text::CSV`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV) with `\t` character as the delimiter, extract wanted values and write to file

Comment: all true, but OP may need a concrete example of one of the other